# Arduino port not showing serial USB Mac OS El Capitan

Tags: arduino-uno

I don't see serial USB as an option under ports when my Arduino is connected to my Mac. I have used this Arduino on the same computer before without any issues on Yosemite OS. However, I was trying to run a servo motor and I don't think I was getting enough power so I decided to use an external power supply. 12V 500mA DC and connected it while still keeping the USB connection. Since I already had the servo program loaded, the motor did work. Then I tried uploading the program again, that's when I realized that there was no serial connection. I am not sure if the problem is because of the power supply that I connected.

I tried the following approaches without success:

1. Upgraded the OS to El Capitan (which might have been a bad decision in hindsight).
2. Tried connecting the Arduino to another Mac with new Arduino IDE download, same issue.
3. Tried downloading the FTDI drivers as suggested by other folks.

I searched for a few hours for a solution online, but nothing so far has helped. Please provide suggestions.

Comment: Possible help [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=351999.0)

Comment: An Arduino UNO *never* requires FTDI drivers - only *other* Arduino boards and fundamentally different designes from *other* sources might require that.  Try disconnecting the motor and its power supply and see if you can program the bare Arduino board when powered by USB.  Also (carefully!) make sure nothing on the board is getting hot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is impossible to diagnose from the limited information provided, and the asker has failed provide any followup for over half a year, meaning this will probably *never* be answered.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change USB ports
2. Check your Tx and Rx pins aren't connected to ANYTHING.
3. Reboot your Mac.
4. If you're really desperate, change OS.

Comment: Already tried 1 and 3 several times. For 2, I don't have any wires physically connected to the board other than the USB cable. I have the servo motor program uploaded on the board and there is no way for me to wipe it out. But that is only using digital pin 9. When I power up the board LED marked L above TX and RX lights up yellow along with the ON led which is green.

Comment: 5. Try connecting another Arduino & cable to your computer. (Two computers not seeing your Arduino sounds like the fault may like with the Arduino.)

Comment: Yes, I tried 2 computers (Mac and windows) and it didn't work. Bought a new board and that solved the problem. Don't know what went wrong with the first board though.